# How can I include 2 specific dates and ticks when plotting Timestamps?

Tags: python, date, datetime, pandas, matplotlib

When I read in data from a csv file, I convert my date information from a string to a `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` using `pd.to_datetime(df.date)`.  From here, I can plot the data, and get something like the following:

[image]

I have two problems:

1. The dates have to be rotated, which is deceiving.  It looks as if that huge spike occurs in Dec 2014, when in reality, it occurs in February of the following year.
2. The date of the huge spike is of relative importance, while the other dates (except Dec 2014) are not.

I would like to:

1. Be able to write the year underneath the month in order to be more economic with space, or add ticks on the x axis so that it is unambiguous where the xticks point to.
2. Be more conservative with my xticks, and ensure that Dec 2014 and Feb 2015 are included as ticks, always.

I understand pandas doesn't play well with the Matplotlib date functionality.  How can I accomplish what I want without having to switch to numpy arrays?

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


palette = sns.color_palette()

plt.close('all')

s = pd.read_csv('all_tweets.csv')

t = pd.to_datetime(s.date)

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = plt.gca()

plt.grid('off')
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
ax.axhline(0, color = 'k')
ax.axvline(min(t), color = 'k')
plt.xlim([min(t), max(t)])







plt.plot(t,s.tweet, color = 'k', linewidth = 10, linestyle = '-', label = 'Tweets')

smoothed = pd.ewma(s.tweet, span = 20, adjust = False)
l, = plt.plot(t,smoothed, color = 'r', linewidth = 5, linestyle = '--',label = 'Smoothed')
l.set_dashes([10,6])
plt.xticks(fontsize = 30, rotation = 45)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 30)



plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize = 36,labelpad = 25)
plt.ylabel('Tweets Per Day', fontsize = 36,labelpad = 25)



figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()
plt.savefig("all_tweets.png",bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data that can reproduce your issue?.  I tried to replicate it, but the index printed fine.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzmnSPzMM_U_OHFncXRBLWpGcXc/view?usp=sharing  Here is a link to the csv file

Comment: I should mention, this data is only for the black curve.  I purposely rotated the dates so that they could be read.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I need to post it as such so that you can view the graphic.  Given your data from the link above and the following transformations, this is my chart:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_location...)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet, that is almost exactly what I want.  Now, how Can I add February 2015 and December 2014 into the ticls